# How to add row to first empty row? Google spreadsheet API with chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

I successfully created a chrome extension that uses oAuth2 to write to a google spreadsheet.

Now i have the problem that my code just adds my content to the first row and updates that row, whenever i call the function to add new content.

How do i have to change my code to just add a new row whenever i call it but do not update just the first row over and over again??

This is my code:

```
function addRowToSpreadsheet(params){
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, getToken);
function getToken(token) {
    let init = {
        method: 'PUT',
        async: true,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
        contentType: 'json',
    };
    fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/KEY/values/A1:K100?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=KEY', init)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {
        });
}}

  function paramCreater(){
     var params = {
        'values': [
            ['Row 1 Col A','Row 1 Col B'],
                    ]
                };
  addRowToSpreadSheet(params);
}
```

I know that i should use the append function from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append, but i don't know how to add it to my code.

Should be added somewhere here right?

```
fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/KEY/values/A1:K100?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=KEY', init)
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

Comment: i found that page @imlokesh but i do not know how to add that append to my code. it should be added somewhere here i guess. fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/KEY/values/A1:K100?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=KEY', init). But no idea how. Do you know how to add it?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are passing through `params`?

Comment: Also, the method should be `POST`, not `PUT`.

Comment: I added the code you required @Iamblichus

Comment: @Iamblichus when i change my code to POST, it does not insert anything at all. I would be very thankful for your help! it seems like you know about this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want to append a new row, you have to do a `POST` request to the following endpoint. At least in the code you provided, you are not adding `:append`:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}:append`

So try changing this line:

```
fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/KEY/values/A1:K100?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=KEY', init)
```

To this one:

```
fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/KEY/values/A1:K100:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=KEY', init)
```

- The HTTP method should be `POST`, not `PUT`. So you would have to change this line:

```
method: 'PUT',
```

To this one:

```
method: 'POST',
```

Because you were not adding `append` and were making a `PUT` request, you were basically calling [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), which overwrites the values in the range you specify.

Then, if you change the `PUT` to `POST` but don't add `append`, you are not making any valid request (there is no `POST` method with that endpoint), so it does not insert anything at all. If you change both things, it should append the data successfully.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks so much! I tried to add the append but i just did not know where and how! And thanks for the explanation about PUT and POST!